# Using Yeoman from Intellij (Idea 12)

Tags: intellij-idea, yeoman

Using OSX 10.8.4, Idea 12. Node v0.10.17, yo v1.0.3

When attempting to use Yeoman as an external tool in I get

```
/usr/local/bin/yo angular
env: node: No such file or directory
```

When I run the same command from bash it works correctly.
What am I missing in my Intellij configuration?

Here's how I have it setup ...

```
Program: /usr/local/bin/yo
Parameters: angular
```

Comment: Could you please echo your $PATH in terminal?

Comment: iMac:~ sja$ echo $PATH
/opt/subversion/bin:/Users/sja/Tools/mongodb-osx-x86_64-1.8.2/bin:/Users/sja/Tools/scripted/bin:/Users/sja/Tools/apache-cxf-2.4.0/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/sja/Tools/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin:/Users/sja/Tools/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: Why was this down voted?  If it is a stupid question tell me why it's stupid.

Comment: Found the cause and a workaround, still looking for a real fix (I'll figure it out soon).  The issue is that GUI apps have a different path than terminal apps.  So the workaround is to start Idea from the terminal then my external tool config for Yeoman works fine.

Comment: So, whoever down voted this knew the answer but was too cool to share or had no clue and was just trolling.

Comment: just upvoted, i hate when people downvote without saying anything. I wonder if this will help? - link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this for a different project. I fixed it by opening the executing .js file (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/[*project_name*]/bin/[*executing.js*]) in vim and using the following command

:set ff=unix