# Yeoman returns 'env: node\r: No such file or directory'

Tags: macos, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I've followed these instructions to
[installing Yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Getting-Started). Everything is fine until I cd into the directory and execute `yo webapp`from the terminal (Also tried `sudo yo webapp`). It returns `env: node\r: No such file or directory` and I never reach the step to choose the kind of web app. Any ideas? On Mac Os 10.9. Updated Ruby, Node.js, Git. And from what I've read Yeoman installs Grunt and Bower.

Comment: Looks like it might be the same problem as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431107/using-yeoman-from-intellij-idea-12 ? Related to node being in the path? OSX installs node into `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. I think there needs to be a special video tut for us Mac rejects on how to properly install Yeoman. I did install node and npm via Mac package installer instead via terminal. And Yeoman via terminal. So, what's the easiest way to rectify the situation so everything plays nice?

Comment: I have successfully verified the existence of node, npm, grunt and bower to be installed and current by checking `bower --version` for example. But, if I check `yo --version` it gives me the same error. Yet, I didn't receive any errors upon installation. And I see it here: `/usr/local/bin/yo` So, it's there…?

Comment: Think the best bet is for you to remove all of them and the install Node via source.

Comment: See the answer on this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504891/yeoman-install-node-path-issues

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Stephen That article solved the problem. Turned out to be Windows line endings in the file that had been published.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this for a different project. I fixed it by opening the executing .js file (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/[project_name]/bin/[executing.js]) in vim and using the following command

```
:set ff=unix
```

Comment: Thanks, this help me!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the version of Yeoman you had back when this was asked used windows newlines `\r\n`. Because of this, at the top of the file, `#!/usr/bin/env node` actually resulted in the shell trying to run a command called `node\r`. (Note the carriage return on the end).

This is probably fixed by now, but this isn't a node issue, it's a windows-newlines-in-osx issue. The carriage returns should be replaced with `\n` newline characters.

Answer (score -1):

open the script with vim.

`:set ff=unix` to modify the format of the file.

`:wq!` to save and exit.