# Yeoman install/node path issues?

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

Took the plunge a couple of days ago, using yeoman for a project. After some fiddling I got it to work on my computer, but then something got messed up and now the project is not running anymore. I think the issue has to do with yeoman installing in one place, but the system looking for it in another. I think, but obviously, I don't exactly know where things are going wrong.

I think the two locations are:

```
Users/brian/
usr/local/lib
usr/local/bin
```

I am not sure where things should be installing for Yeoman. I realize that initially, I was using sudo to install things and that might have messed some thing up, or that I was using homebrew. I have since uninstalled homebrew and no longer need to use sudo for nom to install stuff.

```
$ node -v
```

v0.10.22

```
$ npm -v
```

1.3.14

```
$ echo $NODE_PATH
```

returns nothing.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/brian/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin


$ which npm
```

returns /usr/local/bin/npm

```
$ npm install -g yo
```

Seems to install fine, at the end it says:

```
/usr/local/bin/yo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/bin/yo
yo@1.0.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
```

but if you run yo -v after it says: 
env: node\r: No such file or directory

If I run:

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

it shows the following paths, of which I added the last path:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbins
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

I have node_modules folders in a number of places.

```
Users/brian/node_modules
usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and a number of other places.

Where are things going wrong? Where should npm install yeoman stuff and how does the system refer to it, so it know where it is when I write stuff like $ yo -v

Thanks a lot for any help with this.

Thank you!

Comment: When I install stuff globally, it installs the files into:
usr/local/lib/node_modules

Answer (score 6):

There was an issue with the `1.0.5` launch of `yo`. Try [some solutions from other users](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1236). Basically:

```
$ npm uninstall -g yo
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install -g yo
```

Comment: thank! i am on windows and after i install python easy_install yo was not find the installed generators after i run your commands everything start to work again!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after I changed the default directory for global node installs. And here's I fixed this:

From terminal type:

```
$ which yo
```

In your case the path would look like (or something similar)

```
/Users/brian/npm/bin/yo
```

Now all you need to do is to add this path `/Users/brian/npm/bin/` to the `$PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile` file. Then logout and log back in and type `yo`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bartvds (https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1236)

The reason for this issue is because of the difference in end of line terminators between windows and *nix machines.

The CLI files with shebang when calling node, this end of line terminators are causing issue.

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
```

You can convert the files with this shebang to *nix friendly format using dos2unix utility and it should work fine

This problem is not specific to yeoman alone! I recently encountered the same with interfake node package